Using a pivot table in many different spreadsheets (utilizing the same columns, just different data)
I have many excel spreadsheets that contain the same tables and formats, just the data is different.  I created a pivot table that utilizes the tables in that spreadsheet.  I now need to create the same pivot table (using the same column names but with different data) for each of the additional spreadsheets.  I read that you can create a template (xlt) but I'm not sure how I should proceed.

https://docs.fileformat.com/spreadsheet/xltm/

Just making a copy of the worksheet containing 'initial/template' pivot table (into a new workbook if needed) and changing the data source may be easier.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-workbook-as-a-template-58c6625a-2c0b-4446-9689-ad8baec39e1e
